# Update table in SQLite based on other table

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, common-table-expression, sql-delete

I have two tables, `A` and `B`. Due to wrongly specified loop I need to delete some rows from table `A` (25k rows).

The tables looks as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE "A" (
    "tournament"    INTEGER,
    "year"  INTEGER,
    "course"    INTEGER,
    "round" INTEGER,
    "hole"  INTEGER,
    "front" INTEGER,
    "side"  INTEGER,
    "region"    INTEGER
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE "B" (
    "tournament"    INTEGER,
    "year"  INTEGER,
    "R1"    INTEGER,
    "R2"    INTEGER,
    "R3"    INTEGER,
    "R4"    INTEGER,
);
```

The columns `R1`, `R2`, `R3` and `R4` specify which `course` (from table `A`) was used in that `round` (from table `A`). To show whats going wrong in Table `A`

```
33  2016    895 1   1   12  5   L
33  2016    895 1   2   18  10  R
33  2016    895 1   3   15  7   R
33  2016    895 1   4   11  7   R
33  2016    895 1   5   18  7   L
33  2016    895 1   6   28  5   L
33  2016    895 1   7   21  12  R
33  2016    895 1   8   14  4   L
33  2016    895 1   9   10  5   R
33  2016    895 1   10  11  4   R
33  2016    880 1   1   12  5   L
33  2016    880 1   2   18  10  R
33  2016    880 1   3   15  7   R
33  2016    880 1   4   11  7   R
33  2016    880 1   5   18  7   L
33  2016    880 1   6   28  5   L
33  2016    880 1   7   21  12  R
33  2016    880 1   8   14  4   L
33  2016    880 1   9   10  5   R
33  2016    880 1   10  11  4   R
33  2016    715 1   1   12  5   L
33  2016    715 1   2   18  10  R
33  2016    715 1   3   15  7   R
33  2016    715 1   4   11  7   R
33  2016    715 1   5   18  7   L
33  2016    715 1   6   28  5   L
33  2016    715 1   7   21  12  R
33  2016    715 1   8   14  4   L
33  2016    715 1   9   10  5   R
33  2016    715 1   10  11  4   R
```

Table `B` looks for this particular example like

```
33  2016    715 715 715 715
```

So, the data should only have been inserted for `course` 715.

I think I need to loop over `B` and get the course-codes for each tournament-year-round combination and only keep these data buckets in `A`. How can I do this? Thanks

Comment: Are all 4 Rx values in table B always the same?

Comment: No, not always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to get all the Rx values from table `B` is with `UNION` in a `CTE`.
Then use `NOT IN` in the `DELETE` statement to delete all rows of table `A` with a `course` that does not exist in the `CTE`:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT R1 FROM B 
  UNION 
  SELECT R2 FROM B 
  UNION 
  SELECT R3 FROM B 
  UNION 
  SELECT R4 FROM B
)
DELETE FROM A
WHERE course NOT IN cte;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/cW11qwyR).

or, with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
DELETE FROM A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM B
  WHERE A.course IN (B.R1, B.R2, B.R3, B.R4)
);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/AdAcMjma).

If you need the columns `tournament` and `year` in the conditions also, change to:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT tournament, year, R1 FROM B 
  UNION 
  SELECT tournament, year, R2 FROM B 
  UNION 
  SELECT tournament, year, R3 FROM B 
  UNION 
  SELECT tournament, year, R4 FROM B
)
DELETE FROM A
WHERE (tournament, year, course) NOT IN cte;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/wPgAhvZQ).

or:

```
DELETE FROM A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM B
  WHERE B.tournament = A.tournament
    AND B.year = A.year  
    AND A.course IN (B.R1, B.R2, B.R3, B.R4)
);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/W5eWHGrP).

Comment: Thank you! And thank you for all your previous solutions!