# Join values of two tables that represent the missing values between those tables in SQLITE

Tags: sqlite, union, common-table-expression, exists

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE holes (`tournament_id` INTEGER, `year` INTEGER, `course_id` INTEGER, `round` INTEGER, `hole` INTEGER, `front` INTEGER, `side` INTEGER, `region` INTEGER);
```

With the following data sample

```
INSERT INTO holes (`tournament_id`, `year`, `course_id`, `round`, `hole`, `front`, `side`, `region`) VALUES
  ('33', '2016', '895', '1', '1', '12', '5', 'L'),
  ('33', '2016', '895', '1', '2', '18', '10', 'R'),
  ('33', '2016', '895', '1', '3', '15', '7', 'R'),
  ('33', '2016', '895', '1', '4', '11', '7', 'R'),
  ('33', '2016', '895', '1', '5', '18', '7', 'L'),
  ('33', '2016', '895', '1', '6', '28', '5', 'L'),
  ('33', '2016', '895', '1', '7', '21', '12', 'R'));
```

In addition, I have another table `tournaments`

```
CREATE TABLE tournaments (`tournament_id` INTEGER, `year` INTEGER, `R1` INTEGER, `R2` INTEGER, `R3` INTEGER, `R4` INTEGER);
```

With data

```
INSERT INTO tournaments VALUES
  (33, 2016, 715, 715, 895, 400);
```

The values for `R1`, `R2`, `R3` and `R4` present ids of the courses.
I want the columns `tournament_id`, `year` and `course_id` that are *missing* in table *holes* based on all the possible values of table `tournaments`.
With the help of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74590343/7959614) I tried the following:

```
WITH h AS (
SELECT DISTINCT tournament_id, year, course_id
FROM holes)

SELECT t.tournament_id, t.year
FROM tournaments t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM h
  WHERE h.tournament_id = t.tournament_id
  AND h.year = t.year
  AND h.course_id IN (t.R1, t.R2, t.R3, t.R4)
);
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/iQiBoK7T)

The above goes a long way but I also want the `h.course_id` that is/are missing. Desired result:

```
33  2016  715
33  2016  400
```

These combinations of tournament_id, year and course_id are not present in `holes`. However, they do exists because they are present in `tournaments`.

Comment: Apart from the fact that 1) it is customary to use *id* for a unique identifier and doing the opposite makes it quite difficult to deal with such a database, and 2) your schema is obviously not normalized; what your goal is unclear and what is the second row in the desired result is also unclear.

Comment: What do you mean by *missing in both tables*? 715 and 400 are missing only in `holes`. Also remove the `,` before `FROM tournaments t` in your query (this is the reason for the error that you get).

Comment: @PChemGuy I will change `id` to `tournament_id`. Thanks for the tip.  I will change the question to make things more clear.

Comment: @forpas I edited the question to make everything hopefully more clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this requirement you need a resultset consisting of all the values of the `Rx` columns which you can get with `UNION` in a `CTE`.
Then you can use `NOT EXISTS` to get all the combinations of `id`, `year` and `course` that do not exist in `holes`:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT id, year, R1 AS course FROM tournaments 
  UNION 
  SELECT id, year, R2 FROM tournaments 
  UNION 
  SELECT id, year, R3 FROM tournaments 
  UNION 
  SELECT id, year, R4 FROM tournaments
)
SELECT c.*
FROM cte c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM holes h
  WHERE (h.id, h.year, h.course) = (c.id, c.year, c.course)
);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/lrAgY3AS).